# Magento /pub/static is not writable - Permissions error

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions

So I'm fairly new to Magento, in fact, it's my first time messing with Linux permissions.
I've been asked to change a few things on a website, and I can't even pass through the permissions part.

I think that I messed the permissions on the machine that the website is stored on, in fact, I know that I did it.

I searched stack overflow and Magento StackExchange for similar questions and all the solutions I found did not work on my problem, or at least they haven't applied the right way:

**The commands I used:**

**Permission**

```
sudo find . -type  f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type  d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

**Magento CLI Commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I have little to no experience using Linux/Unix commands and I think it might be that that is making me have a hard time understanding

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm trying my best to understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :apache . && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

(you may adjust /var/www/html/magento2 to your site root location)

this command is from the link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-set-two-users

specifically this command:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {}
```

is what you seem to have missed

Comment: is it normal that my html folder does not have anything inside it?

Comment: Likely you Magento root is not /var/www/html/

Comment: oh alright , just checking :p that confirms my suspicions then thx